# Possible to validate only if certain radio button is selected?

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I have two radio buttons at the end of my form, "Yes" and "No". Currently it validates the user input no matter whether a user selects "Yes" or "No".

I would like to validate the input only if he selects "Yes", and display an error message in case he selects "No". Is that possible with ParsleyJS?

I don't know if it is important to mention but I've integrated ParsleyJS only by using data-attributes. I'm not using custom jQuery or JavaScript for the form validation.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could do `data-parsley-equalto="#hidden-field"` and have a hidden field with yes in it, that way if it is no, you can show your error message

Comment: Amazing @Pete, it's working as per your suggestion. Thanks a lot for the quick and solid comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of [@Pete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790982/pete) I managed to solve my problem, so I want to properly answer my question, just in case anyone else will ever stumble upon the same issue.

The input looks like this (imagine there would be a radio buttons next to each of the answers...):
**Are you under 18 years old?**


*Yes*

*No*

```
<label>Are you under 18 years old?</label>
<input type="hidden" id="no" value="no">
<input type="radio" id="form-s-r" name="radio" value="yes" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-multiple="radio" data-parsley-error-message="You need to be at least 18 years old. Thank you for your interest in our services.">
<label for="form-s-r">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" id="form-s-r1" name="radio" value="no" data-parsley-equalto="#no" data-parsley-multiple="radio">
<label for="form-s-r1">No</label>
```

The general functionality is that if a user says "Yes" the form will **not** validate. Instead the `data-parsley-error-message="You need to be at least 18 years old. Thank you for your interest in our services."` will show up.

This is being achieved by adding the attribute `data-parsley-equalto="#no"` as only the second radio button ("No") will match the requirement, to be equal to the hidden input with `id="no"`.